# Which Blender version I should use to render on an A100

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have access to a NVIDIA A100 GPU and I am trying to replicate [this work](https://github.com/Sin3DM/Sin3DM). Which Blender version should I install to use the A100? With Blender 3.0, I get the error

```
File "/usr/bin/blender/3.0/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Failed to load CUDA kernel from '/usr/bin/blender/3.0/scripts/addons/cycles/lib/kernel_compute_75.ptx' (Unsupported PTX version)
```

I installed Blender 3.0 on my local machine, which has an RTX 3060, and the code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to GPU rendering, the current requirements (for v3.5 and unchanged for Nvidia GPUs since v3.0) are to have either a compute capability >= 3.0 for using CUDA, or >=5.0 for using OptiX with a driver version of at least 470.
[GPU Rendering — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware)

Your A100 have a compute capability of 8.00, so it should be compatible afaik.
[CUDA GPUs - Compute Capability | NVIDIA Developer](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#collapseOne)

So I guess it could be more a driver issue?

Comment: That's great to hear! I will double-check the drivers' versions.